# IE11 support with Angular 13

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular13

I know by default angular 13 doesn't support IE11.Does anyone have some experience how to make it work? Is there any chance those two versions works together?

Comment: Hi @Darko Radisavljevic. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is impossible since Angular has officially removed its support for IE11. However, if you have such a demand, you can use Angular 12 as said in the [blog](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296):

> Thanks to everyone who participated in the request for comments (RFC).
> Developers who still need to support IE11 users for existing projects
> can continue to use Angular v12 and it will be supported until
> November 2022.